# HostName mismatch: use a domain name (ex. https://myname.myorg.com) instead of https://localhost:port

Tags: html, ajax, qt, ssl, hostname

I have a html application that sends an AJAX request to a Qt C++ HTTP Server on my local computer (hosted at `"https://localhost:8081"`) but the AJAX request seems to fail due to host name mismatch issue. My question is "Are there any possible solutions that will allow me use my wild card certificate usable in my Qt Application" or is there any way that I could redirect all requests to a certain domain (valid for my certificate) to a localhost URL in my machine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had this problem solved.

This link is a good start for people who will have the same problem:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1463/Using-http-www-yourname-com-instead-of-http-localh